# Console outputs NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set an interval on a method inside an object. JavaScript seems to make a really weird behaviour. Outputtting NaN.

```
var bar = {
        width:0,
        move:function() {
            this.width++;
            console.log(this.width);
        }
    }
   setInterval(bar.move,100);
```

Does anybody know how to solve this kind of problem? It looks like it doesn't really understand the `this` keyword.

Comment: `setInterval(bar.move.bind(bar), 100);`

Comment: Since that specific function wants to refer to that specific object, it would make sense to use `bar` instead of `this` inside the `move` function.

Comment: @Pointy: Answer section please!!!

Comment: @squint: I disagree. That way fragile code lies. You want to be able to rename `bar` and have all its "methods" still work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think that assumes too much... but then I was making assumptions as well. Depends on the situation. If `bar` isn't meant to be reused, then it makes perfect sense. If it may accidentally be reused, then that's a bug either way. If the function is meant to be reused, then it shouldn't really be anonymous.

Comment: @squint: Granted. I guess I just don't like the repetition of the object "name". It becomes a bit of a magic number in that sense if you squint at it (lol) for long enough... But like all it takes is to copy `bar` into a variable of a different name and your script is broken.

Comment: Why not use a closure?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do you mean like this ---> var substitute = bar; ? Because it still works in my case. Also changing where var bar points to, stills works (without binding):

Comment: @JMR: How could that work? The function refers to `bar`, not `substitute`. (You may need to clone rather than simply assign, in order to notice the difference; I don't remember how JS's reference semantics work)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Depends on what you mean by "copy". If you mean a full clone, then I would tend to suggest that there are deeper design problems anyway. But still, we're letting our experiences direct our imaginations, and as such, I can't disagree but neither can I wholly agree. Too many "ifs". Given the `setInterval` use, It seems that the OP intends a strong coupling... but then who knows.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just tried it out on Chrome's console -->         var bar = {
        width:0,
        move:function() {
            console.log(bar.width);
        }
    };
bar.move(); ----> PRINTS 0. 
var subs = bar;
subs.move(); ---> PRINTS 0

Comment: @JMR: None of your code modifies `width`. (And, again, you may need to do a proper clone rather than just reference-assign.)

Comment: @JMR: You're right, in that it will work from any variable reference as long as the original variable reference remains, because they're just two different references to the same object. If `bar` gets replaced with a new object, then `subs` will be operating on the new `width`.

Comment: @squint excellent, now it gave error. Thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think i would be more suitable setInterval(function() {
        bar.move.call(bar);
    },100);<br> Since it doesn't make any copies of the object it just calls it if you bind it makes copies

Comment: @Dea Yep wish Pointy had written that as an answer!

Comment: @Dea: `.bind()` doesn't copy the object. It just makes a new function with the `this` value permanently bound to whatever you provided. In your above comment, you don't need `bar.move.call(bar)`. You can just do `bar.move()`; it's exactly the same.

Comment: @squint You got an interval you cannot invoke it, the interval itself needs to invoke it

Comment: @Dea: You're passing an anonymous function, which the interval will invoke. Inside that function, `bar.move()` is exactly the same as `bar.move.call(bar)`.

Comment: Why not use a closure? Then you don't have to worry about `this`...

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of a [closure](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)?

```
var bar = (function() {

  var width = 0;

  function move() {
    ++width;
  }

  return {
    get width() {
      // using only a getter makes "width" immutable
      return width;
    },
    move: move // make the move method public
  };
});

var newBar = bar();
var newBar2 = bar();
```

I personally prefer this "[revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)". Not only can you keep variables "private", but it also is highly reusable.

---

**Note: using getters inside object literals is supported in all modern browsers, also IE9+**

Comment: Now that's more like it! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here `this` is `window` object. So it's expecting `width` variable in window context. So if you want your code to be working, you have to context bar as follows:

```
var bar = {
        width:0,
        move:function() {
            bar.width++;
            console.log(bar.width);
        }
    }
   setInterval(bar.move,100);
```

Comment: That's not very reusable though. It would be better to _actually_ set the `this` context. Pointy showed how but, unfortunately, in the comments section.